# Exception with type definition for random-string module

Tags: node.js, module, typescript

I am trying to write a .d.ts for [random-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/random-string).

I have this code:

```
declare module "random-string" {
    export function randomString(opts?: Object): string;
}
```

I am able to import the module no problem then with:

```
import randomString = require('random-string');
```

and invoke:

```
console.log(randomString); // --> [Function: randomString]
```

However, this doesn't work with or without an argument:

```
console.log(randomString({length: 10});
console.log(randomString());
```

I get this error from tsc:

> error TS2088: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.

I looked in the source for random-string and found this code for the method I am trying to interface with:

```
module.exports = function randomString(opts) {
   // Implementation...
};
```

I managed to write a .d.ts for the CSON module, no problem, but that was exporting a 'class' rather than a function directly. Is that significant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration says there is a module named `random-string` with a function named `randomString` within it...

So your usage should be:

```
console.log(randomString.randomString({ length: 10 }));
console.log(randomString.randomString());
```

If the module does actually supply the function directly, you should adjust your definition to do the same:

```
declare module "random-string" {
    function randomString(opts?: Object): string;

    export = randomString;
}
```

This would allow you to call it as you do in your question.